# How do I read XML as an array, like json_decode does? (But in c#)

Tags: c#

I'd like to simply read XML from a String into an array, so I can do stuff like

`xml["element"]["subelement"]`.

But for some reason there are only way more complicated solutions online.
So is there an C# and XML equivalent of the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function?

Comment: I suggest you use LINQ to XML - then you can use `xml.Element("element").Element("subelement")` which is far from "way more complicated".

Comment: You can use `XmlSerializer` to parse the `xml`.Then you'll be able to access the information as a strongly typed object.

Comment: have tried desealization of xml ?

Comment: @JonSkeet Will try this solution, you might not find it answerworthy yourself but I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse your xml file into a dataTable and then use it with rows and column as you wanted to do :

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        //Here you put the path of your xml file , a string path ( mine is from my asp.net project )
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(Properties.Resources.xmlfile);

        //Create a new DataSet that will store your dataTable
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        //"READ" your xml file
        XmlNodeReader xnr = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc);
        ds.ReadXml(xnr);

       //Get your dataTable
       DataTable dt_xml = ds.Tables[0];
```

Now you can use `dt_xml` to use your xml data as a simple DataTable.

Comment: And if the data structure changes?

Comment: He'll need to adjust the use of his data, like in every programming langage,  but the DataTable will always works and store the data properly