# Load an xml file to Datagrid view and saved it again after update

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I have an xml file like this:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">

<configes>

<Username>Administrator</Username>

<Password>123456</Password>

<Domain>sample</Domain>

<Url>http://sample/Organization.svc</Url>

</configes>
```

I loaded it into a datagridview by something like this:

```
DataGridViewRow row;
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(txtXmlAdd.Text);
XmlElement elm = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodeList =  elm.ChildNodes;
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    row = (DataGridViewRow)dgvXML.Rows[0].Clone();
    row.Cells[0].Value = node.Name ;
    row.Cells[1].Value = node.InnerText;
    dgvXML.Rows.Add(row);
 }
```

Now, I want to change some of attributes(edit value, or add new attribute) and save it to the same file again.
I try this but it doesn't work:

```
DataTable dT = GetDataTableFromDGV(dgvXML);
DataSet dS = new DataSet();
dS.DataSetName = "configes";
dS.Tables.Add(dT);
dS.WriteXml(string path);
```

when GetDataTableFromDGV is something like this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.TableName="";            
string firstCol = "";
string secCol = "";
object[] cellValues = new object[1];
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
    secCol = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    firstCol = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    dt.Columns.Add(firstCol);
    cellValues[0] = row.Cells[1].Value;                    
    dt.Rows.Add(cellValues);
}

return dt;
```

Comment: I posted differents answer that will solve  your problem, you can use your xml file as a DataTable :) ,my answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261881/editing-xml-on-live-in-c-deleting-nodes-that-contain-specific-value/38262575#38262575  and here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180836/how-do-i-read-xml-as-an-array-like-json-decode-does-but-in-c/38181110#38181110

Comment: As I told in my question, I could load xml file without any problem. I just want to save it in the same formt after updating DGV.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# Save DataGridView to Xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43053387/c-sharp-save-datagridview-to-xml-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it simple.

Define form field (not local variable):

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
```

Load data from the file:

```
dataSet.ReadXml(filename);
```

Bind DataTable to DataGridView:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

The data will be displayed in DataGridView. Now you can edit them.

Save data to the file:

```
dataSet.Tables[0].WriteXml(filename);
```

---

If you want show each column and its value in a row then you have two variants.

1. Change the xml file format as follows:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Root>
     <configes>
       <Name>UserName</Name>
       <Value>Administrator</Value>
     </configes>
     <configes>
       <Name>Password</Name>
       <Value>123456</Value>
     </configes>
     <configes>
       <Name>Domain</Name>
       <Value>sample</Value>
     </configes>
     <configes>
       <Name>Url</Name>
       <Value>http://sample/Organization.svc</Value>
     </configes>
   </Root>
   ```

   In that case you can use short and clean C#-code above.
2. If you can't change the format of the xml file, then you have to parse it manually and put the values in the DataTable.

Comment: Now in datagridview xml file shows in one row and different column(as much as xml nodes). how could I show each column and its value in a row?

Answer (score 0):

As I told you in my comment, the solution to your problem is in an old answer here: [Editing xml on live in C#. Deleting nodes that contain specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261881/editing-xml-on-live-in-c-deleting-nodes-that-contain-specific-value/38262575#38262575)

But if you want I can rewrite this for you ....

Assuming you have your xml file stored in a dataTable, if you edit the data in this dataTable you can rewrite your xml file like the first one.

```
//READ THE XML FILE
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
//My path
xmlDoc.LoadXml(Properties.Resources.test);

//Read the xml file into a dataSet
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
XmlNodeReader xnr = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc);
ds.ReadXml(xnr);

//Your data will be store in the 4's dataTable of the dataSet ( the <field> )
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
{
    //RemoteAt will remove all the node, so the node <Field> in your example data
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][i] = "NEWVALUE";
    //If you want to only remove the node <Value>  (and not all the <Field> node ) just do ds.Tables[4].Rows["Value"]=null;
}
//Write your new content in a new xml file

//As you wanted here you just read the new xml file created as a string
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
{
    ds.WriteXml(xmlTextWriter);
    xmlTextWriter.Flush();
    stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    //Here the result is in stringWriter,  and  there is 6 <Field> nodes, and not 8 like before the suppress
}

//If you want to create a new xml file with the new content just do 
ds.WriteXml(pathOfTheFirstXmlFile);
//( like rewriting the previous xml file )
```

My input: ( test.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configes>
<Username>Administrator</Username>
<Password>123456</Password>
<Domain>sample</Domain>
<Url>http://sample/Organization.svc</Url>
</configes>
```

My output after the previous code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<configes>
  <Username>NEWVALUE</Username>
  <Password>NEWVALUE</Password>
  <Domain>NEWVALUE</Domain>
  <Url>NEWVALUE</Url>
</configes>
```